# Position text after CSS background image

Tags: css, image, text, positioning

I am trying to position text after a background image and am having trouble. The text overlaps the image, which is not what I want.

What is the problem?

Here is a sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test CSS</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #uxFaceBookLink
        {
            background-image: url(icon-social-facebook.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position-x: left;
            background-position-y: 0px;
        }
        .FBLink
        {
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
        #uxTwitterLink
        {
            background-image: url(icon-social-twitter.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position-x: 0px;
            background-position-y: 0px;
        }
        .TwitterLink
        {
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p><a ID="uxFaceBookLink" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="FBLink">Join us on Facebook</a></p>
        <p><a ID="uxTwitterLink" href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank" class="TwitterLink">Follow us on Twitter</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would give `padding-left: YourBackgroundImageWidth; line-height: YourBAckgroundImageHeight;` to `.FBLink` and `.TwitterLink` divs

Answer (score 2):

After messing with it, I finally figured it out. Here is the CSS

```
        #uxFaceBookLink
        {
            background-image: url(icon-social-facebook.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position-x: left;
            background-position-y: 0px;
        }
        .FBLink
        {
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
        #uxTwitterLink
        {
            background-image: url(icon-social-twitter.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position-x: 0px;
            background-position-y: 0px;
        }
        .TwitterLink
        {
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding to your elements in order to bring them in from the edge and stop them from overlapping your images

```
    .FBLink
    {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    .TwitterLink
    {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
```

Comment: The problem also was that the image kept getting cut off and just could not get the image and text nicely side by side. The image is now more or less fine.